# Previous Day High/Low indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Just looking a little more help. I want to change the background colour of the table cell, when the current price is within 1% of the PrevDayHigh level, the cell will have a background colour of Red, but Green at all other times. The same will apply for all the other levels too. Does the code on the last line do that?

```
    //@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day/Second Day/Week High/Low", overlay=true)

// INPUT
labelTextColor = input.color(title='Header Text Color', defval=#FFFFFF)
labelBgColor = input.color(title='Cell Color', defval=color.black) 
labelTextCol = input.color(title='Text Color', defval=#26A69A )  

Red   = color.rgb(255, 25, 25, 25)
Green = color.rgb(19, 200, 25, 25)


tablePosition = input.string(title='Labels Position', defval='Top Right', options=['Top Right', 'Top Left', 'Bottom Left', 'Bottom Right'])
on_off_levels = input.bool(true, title="show/hide High/Low levels")

float PrevDayHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
float PrevDayLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

float PrevSecondDayHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[2])
float PrevSecondDayLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[2])

float PrevWeekHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1])
float PrevWeekLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1])

TT1_def = "Previous Day's High for the current stock"
TT2_def = "Previous Day's Low for the current stock"
TT3_def = "Previous Second Day's High for the current stock"
TT4_def = "Previous Second Day's Low for the current stock"
TT5_def = 'Previous Weeks High for the current stock'
TT6_def = 'Previous Weeks Low for the current stock'

// LEVELS
time_ = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", time[1])

if barstate.islast and on_off_levels
    hi_line = line.new(time_, PrevDayHigh, time_+(time-time[1]), PrevDayHigh, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color=color.red)
    lo_line = line.new(time_, PrevDayLow, time_+(time-time[1]), PrevDayLow, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color=color.green)

    label.new(x=time_, y=high, text="PDH", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_none, size =size.small, textcolor=color.red)
    label.new(x=time_, y=high, text="PDL", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_none, size =size.small, textcolor=color.green)

    if high >= (PrevDayHigh - PrevDayHigh * 0.01)
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="PDH $0,00", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.blue, style=label.style_triangledown, size =size.small, textcolor=color.blue)

    if low <= (PrevDayLow + PrevDayLow * 0.01)
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="PDL $0,00", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.blue, style=label.style_triangleup, size =size.small, textcolor=color.blue)


// TABLE
var table box = table.new(tablePosition == 'Top Left' ? position.top_left : tablePosition == 'Top Right' ? position.top_right : tablePosition == 'Bottom Left' ? position.bottom_left : position.bottom_right, 10, 7, labelBgColor, labelBgColor, 0, color.rgb(116, 116, 117), 1)


if barstate.islast
    table.cell(box, 1, 0, 'PDH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 1, 'PDL', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 2, 'P2DH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 3, 'P2DL', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 4, 'PWH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 5, 'PWL', text_color=labelTextColor)


    table.cell(box, 2, 0, text = str.tostring(PrevDayHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT1_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 1, text = str.tostring(PrevDayLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT2_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 2, text = str.tostring(PrevSecondDayHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT3_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 3, text = str.tostring(PrevSecondDayLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT4_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 4, text = str.tostring(PrevWeekHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT5_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 5, text = str.tostring(PrevWeekLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT6_def)

//New code added here testing
    table.cell(box, 3, 0, text = str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(PrevDayHigh)), bgcolor = bar_index < (PrevDayHigh - PrevDayHigh * 0.01) and bar_index > (PrevDayHigh - PrevDayHigh * 0.01) ? Red : Green, text_color = color.white)
```

Would someone be kind and help me out. Thanks

Comment: What is your question or what is the issue you are having coding that?

Comment: I'm needing a little help to code 1). and 2). in my question. Thanks

Comment: Your indicator doesn't have any plot. Can you edit your question and paste the entire code ?

Comment: That's what I am saying, That's the entire code, I don't know how to add 'plots', which is what I want. So I am asking for help.

Answer (score -1):

...

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day/Second Day/Week High/Low", overlay=true)

// INPUT
labelTextColor = input.color(title='Header Text Color', defval=#FFFFFF)
labelBgColor = input.color(title='Cell Color', defval=color.black) 
labelTextCol = input.color(title='Text Color', defval=#26A69A )  
tablePosition = input.string(title='Labels Position', defval='Top Right', options=['Top Right', 'Top Left', 'Bottom Left', 'Bottom Right'])
on_off_levels = input.bool(true, title="show/hide High/Low levels")


float PrevDayHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
float PrevDayLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

float PrevSecondDayHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[2])
float PrevSecondDayLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[2])

float PrevWeekHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1])
float PrevWeekLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1])

TT1_def = "Previous Day's High for the current stock"
TT2_def = "Previous Day's Low for the current stock"
TT3_def = "Previous Second Day's High for the current stock"
TT4_def = "Previous Second Day's Low for the current stock"
TT5_def = 'Previous Weeks High for the current stock'
TT6_def = 'Previous Weeks Low for the current stock'

// LEVELS
time_ = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", time[1])

if barstate.islast and on_off_levels
    hi_line = line.new(time_, PrevDayHigh, time_+(time-time[1]), PrevDayHigh, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color=color.red)
    lo_line = line.new(time_, PrevDayLow, time_+(time-time[1]), PrevDayLow, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color=color.green)

    label.new(x=time_, y=high, text="PDH", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_none, size =size.small, textcolor=color.red)
    label.new(x=time_, y=high, text="PDL", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.green, style=label.style_none, size =size.small, textcolor=color.green)

    if high >= (PrevDayHigh - PrevDayHigh * 0.01)
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="PDH $0,00", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.blue, style=label.style_triangledown, size =size.small, textcolor=color.blue)

    if low <= (PrevDayLow + PrevDayLow * 0.01)
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="PDL $0,00", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.blue, style=label.style_triangleup, size =size.small, textcolor=color.blue)


// TABLE
var table box = table.new(tablePosition == 'Top Left' ? position.top_left : tablePosition == 'Top Right' ? position.top_right : tablePosition == 'Bottom Left' ? position.bottom_left : position.bottom_right, 10, 7, labelBgColor, labelBgColor, 0, color.rgb(116, 116, 117), 1)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(box, 1, 0, 'PDH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 1, 'PDL', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 2, 'P2DH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 3, 'P2DL', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 4, 'PWH', text_color=labelTextColor)
    table.cell(box, 1, 5, 'PWL', text_color=labelTextColor)

    table.cell(box, 2, 0, str.tostring(PrevDayHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT1_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 1, str.tostring(PrevDayLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT2_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 2, str.tostring(PrevSecondDayHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT3_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 3, str.tostring(PrevSecondDayLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT4_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 4, str.tostring(PrevWeekHigh), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT5_def)
    table.cell(box, 2, 5, str.tostring(PrevWeekLow), text_color=labelTextCol, tooltip = TT6_def)
```

...

Comment: Hi @ben-Wilson Many thanks for the help, just what I'm looking for, would it be possible to change the code and move the 'PDh' and 'PDL' over to the right hand side and above  the lines? I've taken a screenshot [link](https://www.tradingview.com/x/QsjqyE2Y/) Again many thanks

Comment: label.new(x=time_+(time-time[30]), y=high, text="PDH" .....
and above the lines? - yloc=yloc.abovebar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).